# [vue-test-utils]: wrapper.setChecked() must be passed a boolean

Tags: javascript, testing, vue.js, radio-button, vue-test-utils

Using Vue, I have some radio inputs:

```
  <label>
    <input
      v-model="myProperty"
      v-bind:value="true"
      name="myProperty"
      type="radio"
    > True
  </label>

  <label>
    <input
      v-model="myProperty"
      v-validate="input.rules ? input.rules : ''"
      v-bind:value="false"
      name="myProperty"
      type="radio"
    > False
  </label>
```

I'm testing them with `vue-test-utils` and `jest`, where I select and assign a value to my field:

```
let myProperty = wrapper.find('[name="myProperty"]')
myProperty.setChecked(false)
```

According to the [documentation](https://vue-test-utils.vuejs.org/api/wrapper-array/#setchecked-checked), it appears that's how it's supposed to work. But I get this error:

```
[vue-test-utils]: wrapper.setChecked() must be passed a boolean
```

It works, however, when I set the value as `true` instead of `false`. As an experiment, I tried setting the value as the string `'false'`:

```
myProperty.setChecked('false')
```

Then I got this errror:

```
[vue-test-utils]: wrapper.setChecked() must be passed a boolean
```

So how am I supposed to select the radio input I want in `vue-test-utils` when the value is `false`? And what if my radio inputs have strings for values?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to call `setChecked` on another radio input in the group. This will un check all other radio buttons in a group, since only one can be checked at a time:

```js
wrapper.find('[name="other property"]').setChecked(true)
```

In Vue Test Utils we disallow setting a radio button `checked` to false, since this enables you to put a radio-group into a state where none are checked, despite this not being possible as a user.

Perhaps we should reconsider this design decision. If you have a use case, please create a feature request in the Vue Test Utils GitHub repo.